# how to consume my own web api without getting a certificate invalid error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call and consume my own api which is in the same solution as my mvc app, all the request by default are forced to run on https:

I am doing the following:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var productDetailUrl = Url.RouteUrl(
            "DefaultApi",
            new { httproute = "", controller = "ProductDetails", id = id },
            Request.Url.Scheme
        );
        var model = client
                    .GetAsync(productDetailUrl)
                    .Result
                    .Content.ReadAsAsync<ProductItems>().Result;

        return View(model);
    }
```

however I get the following error:

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

I know that I can by pass this issue using the following but this is a security risk in a production environment.

```
ServicePointManager
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your working with a non trusted authority, probably self signed.

You can install the self signed certificate into your trusted CA store.

Here is a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate.aspx) that explains how to do that.

If its already trusted then I guess your API and web app have 2 different domain names and the certificate is issued to only one of them. in that case you might need to issue a [wild card certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) to work with www.example.com (you're web) or (api.example.com).